# divisibility test by induction

Tags: number-theory

Some help to finish off this part..

Prove that $n(n^2 + 5)$ is divisible by $6$ for positive integer $n$.

I need to show that it is also true for $n = k + 1$ .

I have started well though.

Comment: So you want to use induction? What happens when you plug in $k+1$? what do you do with the expression? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: If induction is not mandatory, $$n(n^2+5)=(n-1)n(n+1)+6n$$

Comment: i get 6 m -2k + 3k^2 + 1  for some integer m ,  second part looks ugly...!

Answer (score 1):

As is commented, you do not necessarily need to do induction. However If you want/need to use induction, then the induction step may look like this:
 If $n=k+1$ then

$(k+1)((k+1)^2+5)= k(k^2+2k+1+5)+((k+1)^2+5) = k(k^2+5)+k(2k+1) + ((k+1)^2+5)= k(k^2+5) + 3k^2+3k+6= k(k^2+5) + 3(k^2+k+2)$

Now $k^2+k+2$ is even if $k$ is an even number. If $k=2p+1$, an odd number then $k^2+k+2 =(2p+1)^2+(2p+1)+2 = 4p^2+6p+4=2(2p^2+3p+2)$ i.e. an even number. This k^2+k+2 is even and hence $3(k^2+k+2)$ is divisible by $6$. Now

$$k(k^2+5) + 3(k^2+k+2)$$
Is divisible by 6 since by the induction assumption $k(k^2+5)$ is divisible by $6$ and we just showed that $3(k^2+k+2)$ is divisible by $6$.